# How to perform double click on a list view item/selected item using AutoIT3

Tags: autoit

I need to call double click of a selected item of a list view control using AutoIt3

```
ControlListView ( "WindowTitle", "", "[NAME:lstAAA]", "GetSelected", 10 )
ControlClick ( "WindowTitle", "", "[NAME:lstAAA]", "" , 2)
```

it select item number 10 but it does not perform double click on this selected item

Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You are already sending "2" for the number of clicks to `ControlClick`. This usually should do it.

You could also try to use [`_GUICtrlListView_ClickItem`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_GUICtrlListView_ClickItem.htm) instead. The 5th parameter `$iClicks` is there to set the number of clicks:

```
_GUICtrlListView_ClickItem($ListViewHandle, 1, "left", False, 2)
```

Comment: Good answer. This is how I would do it as well. +1

Comment: On occasion I have had to go with a single click, then send an enter key

GUICtrlListView_ClickItem($ListViewHandle, 1)

Send("{enter}")

Comment: Answer is good, but it seems that Jahirul uses the autoit c# api, and the method _GUICtrlListView_ClickItem(), does not exist there